# Iterating in ruby using an if else statement ...(along w. ancestry gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

Recently started with`rails` along with `ancestry` gem for the first time.

I am attempting to iterate through an array of `Category` objects which are stored in a tree structure via the `ancestry` gem, in order to display buttons, wired to `link_to` to other category objects, a given category is related to.

The first 3 categories in the database are the roots, and so I will eventually not have enough space in the view to display buttons for all descendants. So, if the `category.parent == 'nil'`, I would like to display only the children of given category.

However, for all other category objects, I would like to display all descendants of a given category.

I was thinking something along these lines, as to iterate through

```
<%= current_user.folders.each do |folder| %>
  <% if folder.is_root? %>
    <% folder.children.each do |child| %>
      <%= link_to child, folder_path(child), class: 'btn' %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <% folder.descendants.each do |desc| %>
      <%= link_to desc, folder_path(desc), class: 'btn' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Would anyone be able to advise?

Answer (score 1):

How are your child categories related to their parents? I'll assume the `categories` table has a `parent_id` column.

Given these categories:

```
parent_category = Category.create!
child_category1 = Category.create! parent_id: parent_category.id
child_category2 = Category.create! parent_id: parent_category.id
```

Now you can check if the `parent_id` is `nil` to see if it is a parent category or not, we'll add a self-referential association and scope to the `Category` model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :parents, -> { where(parent_id: nil).joins :children }
  has_many :children, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

Now you can iterate over the parents and iterate over each parent's children:

```
Category.parents.each do |parent|
  parent.children.each do |child|
    # code
  end
end
```

Comment: Which I basically have done ... but, i am having a hard time figure out how to iterate thru based on the id of a given category object ... tx for your response diego, it is appreciated ...

Comment: The `ancestry` gem works exactly as I've explained above. Not sure what you mean by "iterate thru based on the id of a given category". With an `id` you can find a category `category = Category.find id` and then the ancestry gem gives you the `children`  method `category.children`. It has a bunch of methods for navigating your tree of objects https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree

Comment: The is_root? method in Ancestry is what you're looking for.

Comment: ahh, just read your comment, after having edited post as to include code.  Perhaps, I should replace line 'if folder.parent == 'nil', with ' if folder.is_root?', and see if that works.  Any other suggestions, w. respect to code ?  It is appreciated :-) ...